# Factory Girl skips "before_add" callback on Rails Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I can't seem to get FactoryGirl to call my before_add callback with an associated model.

I've got a Course model with:

```
has_many :lessons, dependent: :destroy, before_add: :set_lesson_number
def set_lesson_number
  #stuff
end
```

a Lesson model with:

`belongs_to :course`.

a Lesson factory with:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :lesson do
    course
  end
end
```

and a Course factory, defined [as suggested by the Factory Girl wiki](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :course do
    factory :course_with_lessons do
      transient do
        lessons_count 10
      end

      after(:create) do |course, evaluator|
        create_list(:lesson, evaluator.lessons_count, course: course)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The before_add callback doesn't get called when I do `FactoryGirl.create(:lesson)`, but it does get called if I do this:

```
lesson = FactoryGirl.build(:lesson)
course = lesson.course
course.lessons << l
```

In both cases, course.lessons ends up including lesson.

By the same token, `FactoryGirl.build(:course_with_lessons)` doesn't work with the above Course factory, but if I replace the create_list line with:

```
evaluator.lessons_count.times do
  course.lessons << build(lesson)
end
```

it does. It seems like FactoryGirl is creating the Lessons and setting their Course ID's, but somehow not actually "adding" them to the collection, so I have to do it manually.

Am I missing something about how FactoryGirl is supposed to work? Or about how ActiveRecord works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how `ActiveRecord` works.

If you run the following in your `rails console` you'll see the `before_add` callback on the association is not called:

```
course = Course.create
Lesson.create(course_id: course.id)
```

I imagine `FactoryGirl.create_list` generates objects in a similar way.

The `lesson` needs to be added to the collection in order for the callback to fire. This can be done in a couple of ways.

**1. Create a `Lesson` through `course`**

```
course.lessons.create
```

**2. Explicitly add the `lesson` to `course.lessons`**

```
course.lessons << lesson
```

**3. Explicitly add a collection of `lesson` to `course.lessons`**

```
course.lessons = [lesson1, lesson2]
```

To get the callback to fire, you could modify your factory like so:

```
  factory :course do
    factory :course_with_lessons do
      transient do
        lessons_count 10
      end

      after(:create) do |course, evaluator|
        course.lessons = 
          build_list(:lesson, evaluator.lessons_count, course: course)
        course.save
      end
    end
  end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Definitely helps, Jordan. Thanks!

I'm surprised to see that `Lesson.course = course` doesn't do the job either. I always thought that the collection was just an abstraction over the fact that all these Lessons have their `course_id` set to `course.id` in the database, but this behavior makes it seem like there's an intentionally designed (and somewhat surprising) distinction. Do you know of a reason that distinction is useful?

Comment: `lesson.course = course` doesn't add to the `lessons` collection, therefore the callback isn't fired.  Basically, if you want to fire the callback, you need to operate on the collection. Creating records on the other side of the relationship can be useful when wanting to by-pass callbacks.